# Attentive Convolution with keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, convolution, keras-layer

I've implemented an attentive convolution layer in keras, as described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.00519.pdf).

You can see the code for it at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stoney95/9c71bb7f7008b7d01dcf8f6bf3afaeff)

I'm new to implementing custom layers and it is still very slow. I'm using a lot of `tf.map_fn` and I think this is the reason why it's so slow, but I don't know a different way to do this.
It would be nice if someone has some tips how to improve the layer or general tips on implementing custom layers like how to avoid backend (tensorflow) functions.

I'm using keras 2.1.3 and tensorflow 1.5 as backend.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `tf.map_fn` everywhere?? They're absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you use `tf.map_fn`, you could avoid it everywhere...

Here are some hints (which may or may not make the code faster).

**Casting**

Do you really need to cast the values to float? If (at least) `x[0]` is an embedding, it's already a float, right? (Not sure about the nature of "context")

Lines 37 and 38:

```
text = x[0]
context = x[1]
```

**Why map functions that are already supported in keras?**

For instance, why do this (L42):

```
weighted_attentive_context = tf.map_fn(self._compute_attentive_context, (text, context), dtype=K.floatx())
```

When you can do this?

```
weighted_attentive_context = self._compute_attentive_context(text,context)
```

With:

```
def _comput_attentive_context(self,text,context):
```

**Suggestion for `_compute_attentive_context`:**

```
def _compute_attentive_context(self, text, context):

    #computes the context-score for every vector like equation 2
    temp = tf.matmul(text, self.We)
    scores = tf.matmul(temp, K.transpose(context))

    #why not?
    scores_softmax = K.softmax(scores)


    #computes the context featur_map like equation 4
    res = tf.matmul(scores_softmax, context)

    #why not?
    res = self._weight_for_output(res)
    return res
```

**And why not use a `K.conv1D` instead of all these complicated repeat, concatenation, etc?**

```
def _conv(self, x):
    return K.conv1D(x, self.W1, padding='same')

    #if you have special reasons for what you're doing, please share them in the comments,
    #please also share the exact shapes of the inputs and desired outputs
    #here, you should make self.W1 with shape (filterLength, em_dim, desired_output_dim)
```

**Suggestion for `call`:**

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    #x is a list of two tensors
    text = x[0]
    context = x[1]

    #applies bilinear energy funtion (text * We * context)
    #and weights the computed feature map like in equation 6 (W2 * ci)
    weighted_attentive_context = self._compute_attentive_context(text, context)

    #does the actual convolution, this is still kind of hacky
    conv = K.conv1D(text,self.W1,padding='same')

    added = conv + weighted_attentive_context
    batch = K.bias_add(added, self.bias)
    return batch
```

**Batch matrix multiplication**

For those multiplications, you can use `K.dot()`, following this:

- If batch x weights: `K.dot(x, self.W)`
- If weights x batch: `K.permute_dimensions(K.dot(self.W,x),(1,0,2))`

Considering you have these shapes:

- If batch x weights -> x: (batch, words, emb) | W: (emb, any)
- If weights x batch -> W: (any, words) | x: (batch, words, emb)

The results will be:

- If batch x weights: (words,any) <- this seems the logical choice
- If weigths x batch: (any, emb)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I made some changes in the gist and added some comments on dimensions etc.

Comment: See the hint for matrix multiplication at the end of my answer. (Still you can remove all of the `tf.map_fn`, you don't need them anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented your suggestions (see gist) but that let to another error (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671745/valueerror-none-values-not-supported-training-network-with-simple-custom-layer))