# ValueError: None values not supported. training network with simple custom layer in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I've implemented a very simple custom layer. It just multiplies the input by a weight.

When I try to train the network I get `ValueError: None values not supported.`

I checked my input and output for `None`s but I couldn't find anything. 
Also tried to add bias to the result but didn't change anything.
Also tried different weight initializers but this didn't have any effect.

When I just build the model and predict some results it works, also the output doesn't have any `None`s

Has anyone an idea why training gives the error?

I'm using Tensorflow 1.5 and Keras 2.1.3

#### Edit

```python
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    #shape of x = (batch_size, n, em_dim)
    return K.dot(x, self.W)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.em_dim = input_shape[2]
    self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(self.em_dim, self.em_dim), dtype=K.floatx(), name='weight', trainable=True, initializer='uniform')
```

#### Edit 2

The layer is now available as [gist](https://gist.github.com/stoney95/9c71bb7f7008b7d01dcf8f6bf3afaeff).

I actually want to compute attentive convolution but it didn't work so I tried to return `temp` (line 53) and even that doesn't work.

Traceback of the error returning temp:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/simons/dev/workspaces/germEval/Bachelorarbeit_GermEval2017/TestOutputs.py", line 123, in <module>
    test_attentive_conv()
  File "/Users/simons/dev/workspaces/germEval/Bachelorarbeit_GermEval2017/TestOutputs.py", line 104, in test_attentive_conv
    model.fit([x], [y])
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1646, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 970, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 174, in get_updates
    v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 775, in _run_op
    return getattr(ops.Tensor, operator)(a._AsTensor(), *args)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 898, in binary_op_wrapper
    y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 932, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1022, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 233, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 212, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/simons/anaconda/envs/absa-3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 401, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Comment: Could you provide the definition of your layer?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's enough. If not  I'll create a gist with the whole definition

Comment: Try changinf `K.dot` to `K.batch_dot`.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: What is the `input_shape`?

Comment: Same as x `(bs, n, em_dim)` explicitly `(26,200,200)`. I had a mistake in my question, I've edited it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164706/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-stoney).

Comment: This error may have multiple causes: you forgot the return statement in some function; you're passing a `None` value to something that doesn't accept it; your loss function or custom layer is not differentiable for backpropagation.

Comment: Not related: you should remove line 10, it's a bug.

Comment: I don't think `batch_dot` should be used when multiplying a weight and a batch. It should be used only in batch x batch multiplications.

Comment: I changed `batch_dot` to `dot`. Output-shape is ok as i pass a list of tensors and return the shape of the first tensor.